# No routing or forwarding, plain ssh from server

Tags: iptables, openvpn

I'm currently developing on a system with distributed computers around the country. All of these are sitting behind a NAT and are self-controlled. As a Backup-plan if puppet fails or for other maintenance I thought about a small vpn-network to access the clients by ssh if I need to.

I've already connected the test-client successfully to the server, but I'm not able to ping or ssh to the client or vice versa (which is currently not needed).

The server is also secured by a iptables-setup. I tried couple iptables-entrys which are known for openvpn, but non of them is working.

How do I have to setup the server to get ssh 10.8.0.* or similar working?

Greets, Moritz

UPDATE:
I found a false configuration on the client-side. It was configured as tls-client and not client. This made ping and ssh both ways possible.

Comment: I have found that OpenVPN works really well with puppet.  Since you can re-use the puppet keys and certificates (pki) issued to the server and clients as your keys within OpenVPN.

Comment: When you say you cannot ping or ssh, are you saying you can't doing it from your client or from the server?

Answer (score 0):

I was working on something similar today (connecting to IPMI private LAN IPs). I found that a good way of doing it was to use a PPTP VPN as I couldn't get OpenVPN to play ball.

Pressuming you use Linux; Script I made to do it quickly (modify to your needs, make sure the eth interface in the iptable commands are right):

```
Centos 5:
rpm -i http://poptop.sourceforge.net/yum/stable/rhel5/pptp-release-current.noarch.rpm

Centos 6:
rpm -i http://poptop.sourceforge.net/yum/stable/rhel6/pptp-release-current.noarch.rpm

yum -y update
sysctl -p /etc/sysctl.conf

iptables -F
iptables -A INPUT -i eth1 -p tcp --dport 1723 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i eth1 -p gre -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth1 -j MASQUERADE
iptables -A FORWARD -i ppp+ -o eth1 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth1 -o ppp+ -j ACCEPT
service iptables save
chkconfig pptpd on

echo "localip 10.10.0.1" >> /etc/pptpd.conf
echo "remoteip 10.10.0.50-100" >> /etc/pptpd.conf

echo "ms-dns 8.8.8.8" >> /etc/ppp/options.pptpd
echo "ms-dns 4.4.4.4" >> /etc/ppp/options.pptpd

echo "USERNAME     *       PASSWORD          *" >> /etc/ppp/chap-secrets

service pptpd start
```

Make sure to enable IP forwarding in /etc/sysctl.conf

Further PPTP Help: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-setup-your-own-vpn-with-pptp

Comment: Reliably getting PPTP through firewalls you don't control is going to be a lot more difficult then getting OpenVPN through firewalls.  Getting GRE through some firewalls is not trivial.